# Access 2007, lock all fields on form load with an "edit" button or toggle

Tags: locking, controls, ms-access-2007, field

I am looking for a way to have my form come up locked (so the user cant accidentally modify or delete data) with an edit button or toggle that unlocks all fields.

Is there a button wizard or similar that would allow this, seems like it would be a common question.

This is still my first week in Access and I apologize if this questions is a bit too nooby :)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Allow ... properties.

```
Me.AllowAdditions = False
Me.AllowEdits = False
Me.AllowDeletions = False
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, got it figured with your suggestion and a bit of googling.